# Which encoding should I specify for the serialized data from TextBox controls

Tags: c#, json, winforms, encoding, json.net

Suppose that I have a `TextBox` in my `WinForms` application.

When user clicks a button, the application should send a serialized value stored in this `TextBox` via TCP.

For the serialization I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` library like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
```

Where `credentials` is the object of class that holds `TextBox`'s value.

Then I need to send it over network via `TcpClient` class:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IpAddress, Port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
// ???
```

but I need to convert the `json` string to the byte array first, so I have to specify a text encoding. Which text encoding should I specify to be pretty safe?

I can't just set it to ASCII because user can enter unicode characters.

Comment: use `UTF8` it has the support for Chinese/Japanese characters also

Comment: @Olivarsham In which encoding `TextBox` controls stores theirs text?

Comment: The .NET Framework uses the UTF-16 encoding (represented by the UnicodeEncoding class) to represent characters and strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET Framework uses the UTF-16 encoding (represented by the
 [`UnicodeEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class) to represent characters and strings. So you can use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` to get bytes of string.

For more information:

- [Character Encoding in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Any Unicode encoding (UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, …) can be used to encode Unicode characters. UTF-8 is possibly the most compact, depending on the writing systems used on your text.